# Strange behavior of AJAX return JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

So I request and get the object from the server like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var req= $.getJSON("api/Appointments");
        req.done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $("#ul1").append("<li>" + value.Time + value.Company + "</li>");
            });
        });
        zahtev.fail(function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        })
});
```

and it works, it shows 1 item in the `<ul>`!
But then, when I try to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var req = $.getJSON("api/Appointments");
        req.done(function (data) {
            if ((data.Time == "9:00") && (data.Company == "Laakkonen")) {
                document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
            } else {
                alert("error1");
            }

        });
        req.fail(function (error) {
            alert(error.statusText);
        })
     });
```

it gives me the error1 of the `else` statement! which should be okay if the retrieved JSON object DIDN'T really have 9:00, but like i mentioned earlier in the table is 1 item, which has `"9:00"` and `"Laakkonen"` in it...so it should color the element red.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have combination of data as response:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var req = $.getJSON("api/Appointments");
    req.done(function (data) {
        var result = false;
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if ((value.Time == "9:00") && (value.Company == "Laakkonen")) { 
                result = true;
                return result; 
            }
        });
        if (result == true) {
            document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red";
        } else {
            alert("error1");
        }
    });
    req.fail(function (error) {
        alert(error.statusText);
    });
});
```

If you have single data as a response:-

```
if ((data[0].Time == "9:00") && (data[0].Company == "Laakkonen")) { 
    document.getElementById("A9").style.background = "red"; 
} else { 
    alert("error1"); 
}
```

Comment: yep, this works but why put in `var result = false`? it works without it as well!

Comment: so when it finds the combination of "9:00" and "Laakkonen" it will stop searching? that is awsome if that is the case!